# bash Add text before and after match

Tags: bash, file, grep, match

I have a file consisting of serial numbers and data. I want to make it more readable by adding a number of asterisks and newline before and after the serial number. Here is an example of the file before and after.

Before:

```
SQ3000-5234646
Voltage level in range
Drive acceptable
SQ5050-9821356
CPU speed limit exceeded
Hardware valid
Unconfigured unit
SQ3000-4574886
Keyboard interrupt
```

After:

```
*******************
SQ3000-5234646
*******************

Voltage level in range
Drive acceptable

*******************
SQ5050-9821356
*******************

CPU speed limit exceeded
Hardware valid
Unconfigured unit

*******************
SQ3000-4574886
*******************

Keyboard interrupt
```

I tried this using grep but couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `sed` for that:

```
$ sed '/^SQ/s|^\(.*\)$|*******************\n\1\n*******************|' t
*******************
SQ3000-5234646
*******************
Voltage level in range
Drive acceptable
*******************
SQ5050-9821356
*******************
CPU speed limit exceeded
Hardware valid
Unconfigured unit
*******************
SQ3000-4574886
*******************
Keyboard interrupt
```

Add `-i` option to change the file in-place.

---

Explanation:

- `sed` processes each line
- if current line doesn't match regular expression `^SQ` `sed` will just prints it as is
- otherwise it replaces line by another regular expression:

  - `^\(.*\)$` there we gather line
  - and now we replace it: `*******************\n\1\n*******************` (there `\1` will be replaced by content of line that we grabbed before

Answer (score 1):

What about that `awk` one-liner:

```
awk 'BEGIN { star = "*******************" }
     /SQ....-......./ { printf("\n%s\n%s\n%s\n\n",star, $0, star); next } 1' data
#     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
# The regex should match your serial number format
# here I've only guessed from your sample data
```

If you really don't want the first blank line on the output:

```
awk 'BEGIN { star = "*******************" }
     /SQ....-......./ { printf("%s%s\n%s\n%s\n\n", (NR>1) ? "\n" : "", star, $0, star); next } 1' data
#                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#                                        only output the start empty line if
#                                            this is not the first line
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an `awk`

```
awk '/^SQ[0-9]/ {$0=v$0v}1' v="\n*******************\n" file

*******************
SQ3000-5234646
*******************

Voltage level in range
Drive acceptable

*******************
SQ5050-9821356
*******************

CPU speed limit exceeded
Hardware valid
Unconfigured unit

*******************
SQ3000-4574886
*******************

Keyboard interrupt
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way of doing it with Awk:

```
BEGIN{
    for(;i<19;i++)
        r=r"*"
}
{
    if($1 ~ /^SQ[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{7}$/) 
        print "\n"r"\n"$0"\n"r"\n"
    else
        print
}
```

Run the script:

```
user@prompt$ awk -f script.awk file

*******************
SQ3000-5234646
*******************

Voltage level in range
Drive acceptable

*******************
SQ5050-9821356
*******************

CPU speed limit exceeded
Hardware valid
Unconfigured unit

*******************
SQ3000-4574886
*******************

Keyboard interrupt
```